# Why cannot System.IO.StreamReader read from my custom stream?

Tags: .net, streamreader

I'm in the process of creating a custom stream for an API endpoint in my app. The stream needs to have custom logic that I don't want to get into, but suffice to say I can't use a built-in stream class.

I did the minimum necessary to implement a read-only stream (inheriting from System.IO.Stream) and I've verified that the System.IO.BinaryReader class can read from my stream:

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.BinaryReader(GenerateStream(business, logic))
Dim enc As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
Dim contents As String = enc.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(CType(reader.BaseStream.Length, Int32)))
```

The string "contents" contains the correct string for the entire stream.

However, I would like to be able allow the use of the System.IO.StreamReader class:

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(GenerateStream(business, logic), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd
```

but for whatever reason the ReadToEnd always returns the empty string.

Any ideas?

Here's the stream:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanRead() As Boolean
   Get
    Return True
   End Get
  End Property

  Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanSeek() As Boolean
   Get
    Return False
   End Get
  End Property

  Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite() As Boolean
   Get
    Return False
   End Get
  End Property

  Public Overrides Sub Flush()
   'this method intentionally left blank'
  End Sub

  Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Length() As Long
   Get
    Return 'some business logic'
   End Get
  End Property

  Public Overrides Property Position() As Long
   Get
    Return bytePosition
   End Get
   Set(ByVal value As Long)
    Throw New System.NotSupportedException
   End Set
  End Property

  Public Overrides Function Read(ByVal buffer() As Byte, ByVal offset As Integer, ByVal count As Integer) As Integer
   'I return 0 on an end of stream, otherwise the # of bytes successfully read.'
  End Function

  Public Overrides Function Seek(ByVal offset As Long, ByVal origin As System.IO.SeekOrigin) As Long
   Throw New System.NotSupportedException
  End Function

  Public Overrides Sub SetLength(ByVal value As Long)
   Throw New System.NotSupportedException()
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Sub Write(ByVal buffer() As Byte, ByVal offset As Integer, ByVal count As Integer)
   Throw New System.NotSupportedException()
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking closely at the description of [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) shows, quote:

> If the initial position within the
>   stream is unknown or the stream does
>   not support seeking, the underlying
>   Stream object also needs to be
>   reinitialized.

It further goes on, saying:

> To avoid such a situation and produce
>   robust code you should use the Read
>   method and store the read characters
>   in a pre-allocated buffer.

But, looking under the hood, only Stream.Read is called, it seems, which *should* provide the output you need. But, you do know that StreamReader reads characters, it tries hard to interpret the data as a string. Not sure what happens if it cannot. What does the data consist of?

---

***Update***: Consider the following test code (sorry, C#, but use [a converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to get your code), I did not include the non-implemented methods from the abstract class so as to not distract from the core. Just as a proof of concept, this seems to work with ASCII encoding and without the need to re-init or an implementation for Seek.

```
public class AsciiStream : Stream
{
    private string dataStream = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private long position = 0;

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }


    public override long Length
    {
        get { return dataStream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return position;
        }
        set
        {
            position = value < this.Length ? value : this.Length;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        long bufferPos = offset;
        long max = this.position + count;
        max = max < this.Length ? max : this.Length;
        for (; this.position < max; this.position++)
        {
            buffer[bufferPos] = Convert.ToByte(this.dataStream[(int) this.position]);
            bufferPos++;
        }

        return (int) bufferPos - offset;
    }
}


// call the code like as follows:
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(new AsciiStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
string sToEnd = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Point being: the problem must lie in your actual Read-code or in the business logic you don't show us. The approach you've chosen, on itself, should simply work. Have you tried implementing, by hand, a "read-to-end"? Or with the `BinaryReader`, reading past the end with ReadBytes(many)``?

Comment: The data is characters (in this case encoded in ascii). I haven't tried reading past the end of the stream with the BinaryReader, but I have verified that you can read /to/ the end with a BinaryReader and you get the correct output.

Although perhaps if I implement seeking the problem will just go away. I did miss the description of "ReadToEnd" though. If seeking fixes the problem, this is the answer.

A BinaryReader implementation of ReadToEnd is displayed in the question.

Comment: The problem did lie in my read method. My read method would return 0 if the /current/ read reached the end of the stream. It now returns 0 only if reading from an empty stream.

Comment: No, seeking or not seeking is not an issue. As you've found out, your interface implementation must be correct. It's hard to help with finding such error without seeing all relevant code... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(
    GenerateStream(business, logic), 
    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, 
    False
)
Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd
```

Also make sure all the methods you don't want used will throw `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: They're throwing NotSupportedExceptions like System.IO.Stream warns can happen. Are you sure that you don't mean NotSupportedException instead of NotImplementedException?

Comment: @Evan - It actually doesn't matter. The reason I recommend this is because if the Stream Reader calls these methods expecting something to happen it will throw and thus make your debugging easier.